# Javascript not affecting HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a simple webpage. Why doesn't the textarea's width change when the browser is resized?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.width=window.innerWidth;
    }
    window.onresize = resize;
    window.onload = resize;
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<textarea id="main" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0;" >It was a dark and stormy night, and the rain came pouring down... </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Phil The OP is running it onload...How is it not there? If only we could downvote comments.

Comment: @epascarello oops. Skim reading questions is not advised :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who chimed in with the right answer. I'm a little rusty with this stuff.

Comment: @Phil I'd been trying to for the past 7 minutes... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style.width` requires a unit to be set, like `px`.

```
document.getElementById("main").style.width=window.innerWidth + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<textarea id="main" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0;" >It was a dark and stormy night, and the rain came pouring down... </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.width=window.innerWidth + 'px';
    }
    window.onresize = resize;
    window.onload = resize;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would this fix the problem?

Comment: Ok, I retracted my downvote, but why move the script below the textarea? As stated in the comments under the question, it's running at `window.onload` and `window.onresize`. The element exists when the function executes. True, this won't hurt anything, but there should be a reason for suggesting to do this.

Comment: @Travesty3 This is my habit when I use javascript to make sure my code will always run even if not 'onload'. I think it's good to change.

Comment: I think instead of just adding a block of code as your answer, it would be helpful to include **why** it solves the problem

Comment: Sorry about that. But I'm not really good at English. I'm Vietnamese :D. I will try so hard, thanks for remind.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line to this:

```
document.getElementById("main").style.width=window.innerWidth + 'px';
```